# The dangers of overwriting JavaScript object and functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5

The nature of JavaScript allows for its native objects to be completely re-written. I want to know if there is any real danger in doing so!

Here are some examples of native JavaScript objects

```
Object
Function
Number
String
Boolean
Math
RegExp
Array
```

Lets assume that I want to model these to follow a similar pattern that you might find in Java (and some other OOP languages), so that Object defines a set of basic functions, and each other object inherits it (this would have to be explicitly defined by the user, unlike Java, where everything naturally derives from object)

**Example:**

```
Object = null;
function Object() {
   Object.prototype.equals = function(other) {
      return this === other;
   }

   Object.prototype.toString = function() {
      return "Object";
   }

   Object.equals = function(objA, objB) {
      return objA === objB;
   }
}

Boolean = null;
function Boolean() {
}
extend(Boolean, Object);  // Assume extend is an inheritance mechanism

Foo = null;
function Foo() {
   Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
      return "Foo.bar";
   }
}

extend(Foo, Object);
```

In this scenario, Object and Boolean now have new implementations. In this respect, what is likely to happen? Am I likely to break things further down the line?

**Edit:**

I read somewhere that frameworks such as MooTools and Prototype have a similar approach to this, is this correct?

Comment: The automatic inheritance from the `Object` class **IS** present in javascript too!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari, lets say I do this: var Foo = (function() { return Foo; }); in this instance, Foo is a function()...so how is Foo automatically inheriting object?

Comment: @series0ne everything in javascript inherits from `Object`. You can do `.__proto__` to see what it derives from. Open up your console and do `function f(){}`, followed by `f.__proto__`. You can follow it up all the way to object. The same can be said of anything in js - string, array, whatever. (excluding `null` and `undefined`, but I'd hope that's a given)

Comment: @Snuffleupagus, I tried that: f.__proto__ returned "function()", however f.__proto__.__proto__ returned "Object { }"...so I'm guessing even function() is an object?

Comment: @series0ne Yep, everything.

Comment: MooTools and Prototype really do add lots of things to internal prototypes but nowadays most people don't consider that to be a very good practice and the newer frameworks tend to keep things in their own namespaces.

Comment: @missingno, yes I tried a similar approach. so say I wanted my own Object prototype, that means I would have to do something like Namespace.Object and similarly, other prototypes would have to follow the same rule. From that point onwards, using these seems very long winded as you have to do things like var x = new Namespace.Object(); instead of just var x = Object();

Comment: @series0ne: Well, I think it would be simpler to use static functions insread of creating new classes. So it would be `Namespace.myFunction( the_object )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monkey patching builtin classes like that is a controversial topic. I personally don't like doing that for 2 reaons:

1. Builtin classes are a global scope. This means that if two different modules try to add methods with the same name to the global classes then they will conflict, leading to subtle bugs. Even more subtly, if a future version of a browsers decides to implement a method with the same name you are also in trouble.
2. Adding things to the prototypes of common classes can break code that uses for-in loops without a hasOwnProperty check (people new to JS often do that to objects and arrays, since for-in kind of looks like a foreach loop). If you aren't 100% sure that the code you use is using for-in loops safely then monkeypatching Object.prototype could lead to problems.

That said, there is one situation where I find monkeypatching builtins acceptable and that is adding features from new browsers on older browsers (like, for example, the forEach method for arrays). In this case you avoid conflicts with future browser versions and aren't likely to catch anyone by surprise. But even then, I would still recommend using a shim from a third party instead of coding it on your own, since there are often many tricky corner cases that are hard to get right.

Comment: Note: To mitigate point 2, ES5 permits adding non-enumerable properties which don't show up in a for-in loop. Point 1 is still valid (although, there may be some ways around it if you're clever -- like using iframes to provide different code with different global environments... but there's a lot of difficulties that make this fairly impractical for naive use).

Answer (score 1):

There's some level of preference here, but my personal take is that this sort of thing has the potential to become a giant intractable mess.

For example, you start with two projects, A and B, that each decide to implement all sorts of awesome useful fluent methods on String.

Project A has decided that `String` needs an `isEmpty` function that returns `true` if a string is zero-length or is only whitespace.

Project B has decided that `String` needs an `isEmpty` function that returns `true` if a string is zero-length, and an `isEmptyOrWhitespace` function that returns `true` if a string is zero-length or is only whitespace.

Now you have a project that wants to use some code from Project A and some code from Project B. Both of them make extensive use of their custom `isEmpty` functions. Do you have any chance of successfully joining the two? Probably not. You are in a cluster arrangement, so to speak.

Note that this is all very different than extension methods in C#, where you at least have to import the containing static class's namespace to get the extension method, there's no runtime conflict, and could reasonably consume from A and B in the same project as long as you didn't import their extensions namespace (hoping that they had the foresight to put their extension classes in a separate namespace for exactly this reason).

Answer (score 0):

The worst case in JS that I know of along these lines is `undefined`. You can define it.

You're allowed to do things like `undefined = 'blah';`.... at which point, you can no longer rely on `if(x === undefined)`. Which could easily break something elsewhere in your code (or, of course, in a third party lib you may be using).

That's completely bonkers, but definitely shows the definitely dangers of arbitrarily overwriting built-in objects.

See also: http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/15/undefined-is-mutable

For a slightly more sane example, take the [Sahi browser testing tool](http://sahi.co.in/). This tool allows you to write automated scripts for the browser to test your site. (similar to Selenium). One problem with doing that is if your site uses `alert()` or `confirm()`, the script would stop running while it waits for user input. Sahi gets around this by overwriting these functions with its own stub functions.

Comment: For the record the only browser that seems to have `undefined` as mutable is IE7 and below.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid overriding the default behavior of the inherent objects. It's biten me a few times, while others I was fine. A library you can look at for an example is Sugar.js. Its a great library that some folks love, but I generally avoid it simply because it extends the behavior of existing JavScript objects, such as what you are doing.

I think however that you will find that this is purely opinion and style.